# crypto analysis of my algo

Tags: python, encryption, python-2.7, cryptography, complexity-theory

```
import string,random,platform,os,sys
def rPass():
    sent =  os.urandom(random.randrange(900,7899))
    print sent,"\n"
    intsent=0
    for i in sent:
        intsent += ord(i)
    print intsent
    intset=0
rPass()
```

I need help figuring out total possible outputs for the bytecode section of this algorithm. Don't worry about the for loop and the ord stuff that's for down the line. -newbie crypto guy out.

Comment: Side note: You don't have to do `random.shuffle(li, random.random)`; that's already the default value. And likewise, there's rarely any point mixing up `os.urandom` and the `random` module; that's what `random.SystemRandom` is there for.

Comment: More importantly, what does your question mean? What is "the unicode section of this algorithm"? There is no Unicode anywhere in the code, just integers and byte strings.

Comment: bytecode, sry bout that.

Comment: I don't think you mean [bytecode](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-bytecode) any more than you meant Unicode. You just mean "bytes"?

Comment: Of course there is. If you followed the link, it would be obvious. Bytecode is _code_, in particular an intermediate form of code compiled from source to be run on an interpreter/virtual machine. In the specific case of Python, CPython compiles your source to CPython bytecode, which is described at the link I gave you.

Comment: your talkin opcodes, i'm not...

Comment: You're the one who said "bytecode". That's what bytecode means. If you want to use standard terms to mean something completely different, like Humpty Dumpty, you can do so, but nobody's going to have any idea what you're talking about.

Comment: ok well I feel it's an ambiguous term which can be used in various situations. its byte code to me almost no matter how its displayed but in this case a little more so because this crypto suite is actually putting out random bytes... of code... didn't think it was that complicated sry.

Answer (score 6):

I won't worry about the loop and the `ord` stuff, so let's just throw that out and look at the rest.

Also, I don't understand "I need help figuring out total possible outputs for the unicode section of this algorithm", because there is no Unicode section of the algorithm, or in fact any Unicode anything anywhere in your code. But I can help you figure out the total possible outputs of the whole thing. Which we'll do by simplifying it step by step.

First:

```
li=[]
for a in range(900,7899):
    li.append(a)
```

This is exactly equivalent to:

```
li = range(900, 7899)
```

Meanwhile:

```
li[random.randint(0,7000)]
```

Because `li` happens to be exactly 6999 elements long, this is exactly the same as `random.choice(li)`.

And, putting the last two together, this means it's equivalent to:

```
random.choice(range(900,7899))
```

… which is equivalent to:

```
random.randrange(900,7899)
```

But wait, what about that `random.shuffle(li, random.random)`? Well (ignoring the fact that `random.random` is already the default for the second parameter), the choice is already random-but-not-cryptographically-so, and adding another shuffle doesn't change that. If someone is trying to mathematically predict your RNG, adding one more trivial shuffle with the same RNG will not make it any harder to predict (while adding a whole lot more work based on the results may make a timing attack easier).

In fact, even if you used a subset of `li` instead of the whole thing, there's no way that could make your code more unpredictable. You'd have a smaller range of values to brute-force through, for no benefit.

So, your whole thing reduces to this:

```
sent = os.urandom(random.randrange(900, 7899))
```

The possible output is: Any byte string between 900 and 7899 bytes long.

The length is random, and roughly evenly distributed, but it's not random in a cryptographically-unpredictable sense. Fortunately, that's not likely to matter, because presumably the attacker can see how many bytes he's dealing with instead of having to predict it.

The content is random, both evenly distributed and cryptographically unpredictable, at least to the extent that your system's `urandom` is.

And that's all there is to say about it.

However, the fact that you've made it much harder to read, write, maintain, and think through gives you a major disadvantage, with no compensating disadvantage to your attacker.

So, just use the one-liner.

---

I think in your followup questions, you're asking how many possible values there are for 900-7898 bytes of random data.

Well, how many values are there for 900 bytes? `256**900`. How many for 901? `256**901`. So, the answer is:

```
sum(256**i for i in range(900, 7899))
```

… which is about `2**63184`, or `10**19020`.

So, 63184 bits of security sounds pretty impressive, right? Probably not. If your algorithm has no flaws in it, 100 bits is more than you could ever need. If your algorithm is flawed (and of course it is, because they all are), blindly throwing thousands more bits at it won't help.

Also, remember, the whole point of crypto is that you want cracking to be `2**N` slower than legitimate decryption, for some large N. So, making legitimate decryption much slower makes your scheme much worse. This is why every real-life working crypto scheme uses a few hundred bits of key, salt, etc. (Yes, public-key encryption uses a few *thousand* bits for its keys, but that's because its keys aren't randomly distributed. And generally, all you do with those keys it to encrypt a randomly-generated session/document key of a few hundred bits.)

---

One last thing: I know you said to ignore the `ord`, but…

First you can write that whole part as `intsent=sum(bytearray(sent))`.

But, more importantly, if all you're doing with this buffer is summing it up, you're using a lot of entropy to generate a single number with a lot less entropy. (This should be obvious once you think about it. If you have two separate bytes, there are 65536 possibilities; if you add them together, there are only 512.)

Also, by generating a few thousand one-byte random numbers and adding them up, that's basically a very close approximation of a normal or gaussian distribution. (If you're a D&D player, think of how 3D6 gives 10 and 11 more often than 3 and 18… and how that's more true for 3D6 than for 2D6… and then consider 6000D6.) But then, by making the number of bytes range from 900 to 7899, you're flattening it back toward a uniform distribution from 700*127.5 to 7899*127.5. At any rate, if you can describe the distribution you're trying to get, you can probably generate that directly, without wasting all this urandom entropy and computation.

It's worth noting that there are very few cryptographic applications that can possibly make use of this much entropy. Even things like generating SSL certs use on the order of 128-1024 bits, not 64K bits.

---

You say:

> trying to kill the password.

If you're trying to encrypt a password so it can be, say, stored on disk or sent over the network, this is almost always the wrong approach. You want to use some kind of zero-knowledge proof—store hashes of the password, or use challenge-response instead of sending data, etc. If you want to build a "keep me logged in feature", do that by actually keeping the user logged in (create and store a session auth token, rather than storing the password). See the Wikipedia article [password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password) for the basics.

Occasionally, you *do* need to encrypt and store passwords. For example, maybe you're building a "password locker" program for a user to store a bunch of passwords in. Or a client to a badly-designed server (or a protocol designed in the 70s). Or whatever. If you need to do this, you want one layer of encryption with a relatively small key (remember that a typical password is itself only about 256 bits long, and has less than 64 bits of actual information, so there is absolutely no benefit from using a key thousands of times as long as they). The only way to make it more secure is to use a better algorithm—but really, the encryption algorithm will almost never be the best attack surface (unless you've tried to design one yourself); put your effort into the weakest areas of the infrastructure, not the strongest.

---

You ask:

> Also is urandom's output codependent on the assembler it's working with?

Well… there is no assembler it's working with, and I can't think of anything else you could be referring to that makes any sense.

All that `urandom` is dependent on is your OS's entropy pool and PRNG. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom) say, `urandom` just reads `/dev/urandom` (Unix) or calls `CryptGenRandom` (Windows).

If you want to know exactly how that works on your system, `man urandom` or look up `CryptGenRandom` in MSDN. But all of the major OS's can generate enough entropy and mix it well enough that you basically don't have to worry about this at all. Under the covers, they all effectively have some pool of entropy, and some cryptographically-secure PRNG to "stretch" that pool, and some kernel device (linux, Windows) or user-space daemon (OS X) that gathers whatever entropy it can get from unpredictable things like user actions to mix it into the pool.

So, what is that dependent on? Assuming you don't have any apps wasting huge amounts of entropy, and your machine hasn't been compromised, and your OS doesn't have a major security flaw… it's basically not dependent on anything. Or, to put it another way, it's dependent on those three assumptions.

To quote the [linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom), `/dev/urandom` is good enough for "everything except long-lived GPG/SSL/SSH keys". (And on many systems, if someone tries to run a program that, like your code, reads thousands of bytes of `urandom`, or tries to kill the entropy-seeding daemon, or whatever, it'll be logged, and hopefully the user/sysadmin can deal with it.)

---

> hmmmm python goes through an interpreter of its own so i'm not sure how that plays in

It doesn't. Obviously calling `urandom(8)` does a bunch of extra stuff before and after the syscall to read 8 bytes from `/dev/urandom` than you'd do in, say, a C problem… but the actual syscall is identical. So the `urandom` device can't even tell the difference between the two.

> but I'm simply asking if urandom will produce different results on a different architecture.

Well, yes, obviously. For example, Linux and OS X use entirely different CSPRNGs and different ways of accumulating entropy. But the whole point is that it's *supposed* to be different, even on an identical machine, or at a different time on the same machine. As long as it produces "good enough" results on every platform, that's all that matters.

> For instance would a processor\assembler\interpreter cause a fingerprint specific to said architecture, which is within reason stochastically predictable?

As mentioned above, the interpreter ultimately makes the same syscall as compiled code would.

As for an assembler… there probably isn't any assembler involved anywhere. The relevant parts of the Python interpreter, the random device, the entropy-gathering service or driver, etc. are most likely written in C. And even if they *were* hand-coded in assembly, the whole point of coding in assembly is that you pretty much directly control the machine code that gets generated, so different assemblers wouldn't make any difference.

The processor might leave a "fingerprint" in some sense. For example, I'll bet that if you knew the RNG algorithm, and controlled its state directly, you could write code that could distinguish an x86 vs. an x86_64, or maybe even one generation of i7 vs. another, based on timing. But I'm not sure what good that would do you. The algorithm will still generate the same results from the same state. And the actual attacks used against RNGs are about attacking the algorithm the entropy accumulator, and/or the entropy estimator.

At any rate, I'm willing to bet large sums of money that you're safer relying on `urandom` than on anything you come up with yourself. If you need something better (and you don't), implement—or, better, find a well-tested implementation of—[Fortuna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_%28PRNG%29) or [BBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub), or buy a hardware entropy-generating device.

Comment: @ChromeXavier: Before you clarify, maybe explain what you're actually trying to do before diving into the code that you hope will do it.

Comment: damn, and yessir. the question of "total possible" though, I want to know maximum possible outcomes.
in responce to "Before you clarify, maybe explain what you're actually trying to do before diving into the code" I can't tell you too much but let me think of a concise answer for that.

Comment: the bytes combines with the ord will act together in a key-lock mechanism unfolding a secondary and third layer of crypto underneath.
the first and second are of my own making, the third will be well known and established, ECC most likly.

Comment: tryin to do it on paper... i just dont remember the maths, anyone?

Comment: is it a permutation of 7000!/(7000-256)!   ?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking in your followup, but I'll take a guess and try to answer. Meanwhile… why are you trying to build this in the first place? If you're not a crypto expert, adding your own layer of crypto to something well-known never makes things more secure, and often makes them less secure.

Comment: trying to kill the password. this is a snippet of code from layer 1 of the algo there's mroe to it... i'm not a crypto expert yet but there's only one way to learn.

Comment: Also is urandom's output codependent on the assembler it's working with?

Comment: What do you mean by "kill the password"? Meanwhile, the way to learn crypto is to learn the math first, and study what makes the existing algorithms and systems work, and how they've been cracked. Designing new algorithms by throwing random bits of code together and hoping they're secure does not get your anywhere closer to being a crypto expert.

Comment: And your question about `urandom`… I don't even understand what you're asking. What assembler? And what do you mean by "codependent"? But I'll edit the answer to explain what `urandom` does, and what it _is_ dependent on, in hopes that helps

Comment: hmmmm python goes through an interpreter of its own so i'm not sure how that plays in but I'm simply asking if urandom will produce different results on a different architecture. For instance would a processor\assembler\interpreter cause a fingerprint specific to said architecture, which is within reason stochastically predictable?

Comment: At this point, most of what I'm explaining is background stuff that you should learn before you start trying to design things yourself. Go read Schneier's _Applied Cryptography_, _Practical Cryptography_, and _Secrets and Lies_. Those three books will answer all of your questions, and give you the foundation to understand why they're silly questions.

Comment: in other words you also have no idea? k thnx nice help. seriously your talking down to me about it but i somehow doubt you could answer my last question. listen if anyone could add anything useful here i'd be grateful, i'll be digging in the meantime, as always.

Comment: I _did_ answer your last question. Maybe you couldn't find it because the answer is already pages long from trying to answer all of your followup questions, or explain why they make no sense, and explain all the basic foundational knowledge you should have before trying to design cryptosystems. This isn't the way this site works. The answer is already way too long to be helpful to any future readers. If you have new questions, ask new questions, don't keep adding followups.

Comment: thnx for the help abarnert... you said, "The processor might leave a "fingerprint" in some sense... And the actual attacks used against RNGs are about attacking the algorithm the entropy accumulator, and/or the entropy estimator." What if it's not for an attack but instead a security measure.

Comment: First, a security measure is just something that makes attacks harder. (And a _useful_ security measure is something that makes the most-likely or most-likely-to-succeed attacks harder—a chain is only as strong as its weakest link.) Second, if your code needs information about the system it's running on, it can just read that information directly; it doesn't need to try to guess it.

Comment: "Occasionally, you do need to encrypt and store passwords...put your effort into the weakest areas of the infrastructure, not the strongest." Your talking about technical specs, look at the reality of the situation. Too many hacks irl are social engineering of passwords, if you can even call that hacking...

Comment: "...if your code needs information about the system it's running on, it can just read that information directly; it doesn't need to try to guess it." It's not at all guessing, it would be a stochastic fingerprint as a security measure. Preferably measuring multiple dynamic variables unique to a computer, as unique as possible anyhow. Why heuristics instead of doing something straight forward? I mean to leave the password on the host machine and so I must provide rigorous proof that I am indeed on the host machine. If I do basic fingerprinting it gets hacked easily, heuristics, not so much.

Comment: I do realize that it's a taboo idea, I realize why, and I realize CAs are not working as planned and people shouldn't be trusted with their own security measures in the world of computer science. So I want to harden one of 3 bad choices, the one who got brushed under the carpet for good reason a long while ago... I think all these methods have their weaknesses but if done right the password could be kept on the hard drive and sufficiently protected by strong fingerprinting. Metadata like voltage data, fan rpm data, with the obvious hw name, architecture and such.

Comment: Adding dynamic variables such as fan speed would give you something very personal to tie your tests to and although this could certainly be hacked in the end assuming the fingerprinting goes deep enough to capture a good majority of a computers specs and the metadata in between. I feel this may be a reasonable >start< to removing the password from the equation.

Comment: The whole point of my statement is that you almost never _want_ to encrypt and store passwords. Which entirely solves the problem of insecure passwords. That's why I recommended you read books about crypto _systems_, as well as crypto algorithms. Why do you want to put a password on the host computer's hard drive, instead of designing a system that doesn't require the password to be put anywhere?

Comment: I need to find something aside from bios dependent variables, but not as flaky as high level code. =x

Comment: Why do you need that? Anything meaningful will be _less_ random than what you read from `urandom`, and easier to detect/predict, making your system weaker. Even if you just want to seed an entropy pool (e.g., so you can use Fortuna with a dedicated pool), you're better off just gathering mouse movements or timing user actions (like GPG, etc.) than using something static and unchanging.

Comment: "The whole point...Which entirely solves the problem of insecure passwords. That's why I recommended you read books about crypto systems..." I can tell you have done your research on the white hate side of things but I'm wondering how much black hat knowledge you've gained over the years? "entirely solves the problem of insecure passwords." again most attacks, which aren't sql, are social engineering. - I do read, I also put my knowledge to test in the real world outside the comfort of academia. Still I've got plenty to learn, don't we all...

Comment: My first C program was a fake Unix login prompt to gather passwords, and in my experience about half the "white-hat" types have the same kind of black-hat background. And yet, everyone I know, no matter how brilliant, can remember all the amazing revelations when they first read Schneier's books. If you think you already know it all, you will not learn until your clever system is cracked within 24 hours after someone starts caring about cracking it.

Comment: a know it all asking for help... ya real clever...  "Still I've got plenty to learn, don't we all..."-uhhh who was that again, ohhhhhhhhhhhh yyyyyya rrright... that's me, 2 paragraphs up.

Comment: i really find your attitude deplorable at this point abarnert. I clearly stated that I had plenty to learn by calling myself a newb in the post. I clearly asked for help showing I'm not a know it all. I clearly have understanding of the subject and am trying to expand upon it. What's not clear is what you think I do\don't know. Instead of bothering for a second to have a little give and take in the "conversation" pushing ideas, exploring nuance. You instantly dismiss what you don't instantly get leaving no room for progress. Just keep grinding what you already know, boss.

Comment: I suggest you be real careful in your response, wouldn't wanna come off like a know-it-all after the last 3 paragraphs. Honestly people would learn so much faster if it wasn't for this all to typical mindset. This is so off topic and trashy at this point. Honestly mods if you feel the need for housekeeping, I won't blame you.